# Socket timeout property for db2jcc4 driver for db2 database using Hikari CP

Tags: jdbc, db2, hikaricp

I am connecting to Db2 database through spring boot application (2.1.2 release).. Hikari cp is the connection pool.. Db2 jdbc driver is db2jcc4 4.26.14 . I am receiving Error code - 4499:connection is reset message after my application runs for few days. On restart it starts working fine.
Found in one of the thread setting the socket timeout property may help. Can some one please let me know how to set the socket timeout property for db2 driver.
I have set maxLifetime as 130000, idleTimeout as 120000, ConnectionTimeout as 300000, minimumIdle as 0,maxPoolSize as 10.
Any help will be really appreciated to solve this issue.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

At db2jcc4.jar level, different kinds of timeout settings are availble , and may depend on the **target** Db2-server-platform and Db2-server-version and HA configuration.  Your question omits these facts about your environment.

Examples of settable attributes at db2jcc4.jar level for recent versions of this driver include these below:

```
blockingReadConnectionTimeout
commandTimeout
connectionTimeout
keepAliveTimeout
loginTimeout
memberConnectTimeout
queryTimeoutInterruptProcessingMode
timerLevelForQueryTimeOut
```

Detailed study is needed to comprehend these, and the related settings (and how they relate to Hikari level configuration), as well as comprehensive test coverage.

Documentation below:

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.java.doc/src/tpc/imjcc_r0052038.html